# IPhone UIButton - Swipe vs. Touches

Tags: iphone, uibutton, swipe

I subclassed a UIButton for custom drawing (overriding `drawRect`) and some other custom behavior, out of which the following is relevant (and trivial):

1. If it is pressed (`UIControlEventTouchDown`) a flag "pressed" is turned on (affects custom drawing, kind of like "highlighted").
2. If it is released inside (`UIControlEventTouchUpInside`), my `OnClick` function is triggered.
3. If it is released outside (`UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`), flag "pressed" is turned off.

I now wanted to add an additional behavior to the button so it will recognize swipe gestures (using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`), and affect the button content. The problem is that when preforming a swipe gesture, the `TouchDown` fires, as it really should, causing the button to appear "pressed", which is not my intention during a swipe.

My question is if there is an elegant way to avoid this. Perhaps something similar to `DelaysContentTouches` of a scroll view, that will separate the swipe behavior from the pressing behavior. The only other alternative I can see, is messing around with timers my self, which I would prefer avoiding if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DannyA. Here is my solution:

Use also `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapAction:)];
```

Then, implement this in `didTapAction:` selector

```
[UIButton setHighlighted:YES];

[UIButton performSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:) withObject:NO afterDelay:0.15];
```

That work fine for me.